# Properties of the matrix rank

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

Let $I$ be the identity matrix $n\times n$, B a matrix $n{\times} n$ and $c$ a constant. Are these properties correct?$\DeclareMathOperator{rank}{rank}$
$$\rank(cB)=c\rank(B),$$
$$\rank(I-B)=n-\rank(B).$$

Comment: First is also incorrect in general. $c$ cannot be any constant.

Comment: there is some useful properties for the  expressions?

Comment: @Javier "Useful" depends on what you're using these for. What is it that is known about $B$, and what do you want to do with $B$?

Comment: @Javier One thing that can be said about $\operatorname{rank}(I - B)$ is that this rank is equal to $n - \dim \ker (I - B)$, where we note that $\ker (I - B)$ is the eigenspace of $B$ associated with the eigenvalue $1$.

Comment: If you have no comments, you may want to accept one of the answers. Otherwise the question is listed as "unanswered".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Both are wrong:

The first would imply, if the rank of $B$ is positive, that the rank of $cB$ tends to $\infty$ as $c$ gets larger and larger.

Actually, $\operatorname{rank}cB=\operatorname{rank}B\;$ if $\:c\ne 0$.

The second  would imply that if $B$ is invertible, i.e. has full rank, that $I-B$ has rank $0$, i.e. $B=I$.

Comment: there is some useful properties for r(I-B)?

Comment: @JavierMariño: I don't know any. It seems everything may happen, as  if $B$ is nilpotent, hence has rank $<n$, $I-B$ is invertible, and therefore has full rank.